# IIS redirects to wrong login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am running an ASP.NET MVC3 web application in IIS 7.5.

When a page is requested that requires authentication, the browser should be redirected to ~/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=...
Instead the browser is redirected to: Account/Login?ReturnUrl.

In IIS, I tripple checked the Authentication settings, but they appear to be correct. I've restarted the server a million times, but without result.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does it work on the visual studio development server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this value in the web.config should do the trick

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the follwing :

Add a new class derived from **AuthorizeAttribute** :

```
namespace CustomAuth
{
    public class MyCustomAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/LogOn");
        }
    }
}
```

and then add the attribute to your methods or controllers :

```
 [MyCustomAuth]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Index(int id)
      {
          return View();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose that would work, but it seems a bit of a workaround that shouldn't be necessary.